# PhpStorm file cache conflict with TypeScript compiler

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I've just started using TypeScript in PhpStorm but I keep getting a "File cache conflict" window every time I make changes to my `.ts` (typescript) file. There are three buttons and I have to keep pressing the "Load from memory" button. *Nearly after every single edit.*

This happens a lot after making changes and leaving the PhpStorm window (i.e. when PhpStorm loses focuses).

I did some research and found some solutions

1. Disable Emmet Everywhere - Don't have this plugin installed
2. Remove fsnotifier.exe and fsnotifier64.exe - Did it, no luck
3. Sync files on frame or editor tab activation and Save files on frame - Checked it and Unchecked it - no luck

Please can someone tell me how to stop this? I wish there was a way to tell PhpStorm to make "Load memory" default.

P.S. All files are on my local drive. There is no network involved.

Comment: Such messages usually indicate conflicting change. When a certain file is changed outside of PHPStorm, this can cause conflicts resulting in such messages. do you have any external tools running that may be touching your ts files? Do you have any symbolic links in your project?

Comment: BTW, are you using version control integration? Multiple cache conflicts have been reported by svn users.

Comment: Hi @lena, thanks for the reply. I think you nailed it. My projects folder is in inside the Dropbox folder and after closing the Dropbox app the bug seems to have gone away. I'm not sure if Dropbox was modifying the file, but it seems to be fixed for now. I'm working on the project right now and will update this tomorrow if it happens again.